# Forgetfulness and alcohol (and other narcotics)

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, liquor-beer

Apart from discussions that deal exclusively with the halacha of "ad delo yada", are there any halachic or hashkafic discussions surrounding the forgetfulness that comes with alcohol and other drugs?

E.g. what is the judgement of a person when they can't remember an evening because they were drunk? What happens to those memories? What happens to that person's soul?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Orchot_Tzadikim.9.12-14?ven=Orchot_Tzaddikim,_trans._Seymour_J._Cohen,_Ktav_Pub_House,_1982&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en